# How does Magento determine the route / getting 404 behind proxy

Tags: magento2, nginx, base-url, apache, proxy

I have the following constellation:

- NGINX in front of two apache vhosts
- One Vhost running Magento (port 8181)
- Proxy pass of https://example.de.testing.abc.de/en/shop/ -> http://127.0.0.1:8181

No when I open the website https://example.de.testing.abc.de/en/shop/ I get a 404 on Magento.

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is /en/shop/ (tried with PHPInfo)

The base URL configuration in Magento is as follows:

```
+------------------------------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| Path                         | Scope   | Scope-ID | Value                                    |
+------------------------------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| web/secure/base_media_url    | default | 0        | NULL (NULL/"unkown" value)               |
| web/secure/base_static_url   | default | 0        | https://example.de.testing.abc.de/static/  |
| web/secure/base_url          | default | 0        | https://shop.example.de.testing.abc.de/    |
| web/secure/base_url          | stores  | 1        | https://example.de.testing.abc.de/en/shop/ |
| web/secure/base_url          | stores  | 2        | https://example.de.testing.abc.de/de/shop/ |
| web/unsecure/base_media_url  | default | 0        | NULL (NULL/"unkown" value)               |
| web/unsecure/base_static_url | default | 0        | NULL (NULL/"unkown" value)               |
| web/unsecure/base_url        | default | 0        | https://shop.example.de.testing.abc.de/    |
| web/unsecure/base_url        | stores  | 1        | https://example.de.testing.abc.de/en/shop/ |
| web/unsecure/base_url        | stores  | 2        | https://example.de.testing.abc.de/de/shop/ |
| web/url/redirect_to_base     | default | 0        | 0                                        |
+------------------------------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------+
```

## First question

Can Magento 2 determine from the base URL configuration which store to run?

I am afraid it doesn't ... so I set also the store code

### Further configuration

I am setting in NGINX a header X-MAGE_RUN_CODE=en and check for this header in the Apache Vhost. Then I set the MAGE_RUN_CODE env variable appropriately.

## Second Question

It is still not working - I still get a 404. I verified, that MAGE_RUN_CODE is passed to Apache (via phpinfo() again). MAGE_RUN_TYPE is set to `store`.

I think Magento tries to find a route `/en/shop` ? How can I avoid that? Do I have to use rewrites in NGINX or is Magento capable of doing so?

## update:  Third Question

When I set the proxy to go to the URL / it works - no more 404 page.
But only if FPC is disabled.
If FPC is enabled, I do not get the other language version when changing URLs. Also the language switch appends a __store=en when switching languages. How can I get it working with FPC on?

Seems to be related to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4556

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved it by using

```
            rewrite ^/en/shop(.*)$ $1?__store=en break;
```

and

```
            rewrite ^/de/shop(.*)$ $1?__store=de break;
```

Now only the language switcher is misbehaving.. opening a second question for this.