# Avoid __store in URLs when behind a proxy

Tags: magento-2.2.1, store-switcher

I have this setup in Magento 2

[How does Magento determine the route / getting 404 behind proxy](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203749/how-does-magento-determine-the-route-getting-404-behind-proxy)

- Magento behind a NGINX reverse proxy
- Rewriting store urls from /en/shop to __store=en

Now I am only left with the problem, that the language switch appends __store=en and so on to the URLs.

Can this be elegantly avoided?

References I found:

- [Magento multistore, __store and ___from_store in URL](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53386/magento-multistore-store-and-from-store-in-url)
- A closed issue for Magento 2: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1101